# Manipulating an object from inside a loop that borrows it

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm writing some code in Rust that connects to a remote server, and depending on the messages sent by that server, computes some statistics or executes actions based on these statistics. But this is more of a learning project for me and I've run into an issue.

Here is the code that I have reduced to a bare minimum to reproduce the problem :

```
// Repro code for error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.server` is also borrowed as immutable

use std::collections::HashMap;

struct ServerReader {
    server: Vec<u32>, // A vec for demo purposes, but please imagine this is a server object
    counters: HashMap<u32, usize>,
}

impl ServerReader {
    fn new() -> ServerReader {
        ServerReader {
            server: vec!(1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 9, 1, 1, 5, 6), // Filling my "server" with some messages
            counters: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        println!("Connecting..."); // ... here there should be some code to connect to the server ...

        for message in self.server.iter() { // We wait for the network messages sent by the server, and process them as they come
//                     ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
            println!("Received {}", message);
            self.process_message(*message); // HOW
//          ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
        }
//      - immutable borrow ends here
        println!("Disconnected");
    }

    fn process_message(&mut self, message: u32) {
        // Please imagine that this function contains complex stuff
        let counter = self.counters.entry(message).or_insert(0);
        *counter += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut reader = ServerReader::new();

    reader.run();

    println!("Done");
}
```

While I think I understand why the compiler is unhappy, I'm struggling to come up with a solution. I cannot manipulate my structure outside of the loop, since I have to work while connected and listening to the server. I also could put everything directly in the loop and not call any method, but I don't want to end up with a 1000 line loop (and I'd prefer to understand what an actual solution would look like).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you've worked out, you can't call a `&mut self` method while you're borrowing part of `self`, so you need to restructure somehow.

The way I would do it is to split the state needed by `process_message` into a separate type (in your example that's basically the `HashMap`, but in the real application it's likely to contain more), and move the method to that type.  This works because [you can separately borrow fields from a struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html).

```
struct SomeState {
    counters: HashMap<u32, usize>,
}

impl SomeState {
    pub fn new() -> SomeState {
        SomeState {
            counters: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
    fn process_message(&mut self, message: u32) {
        let counter = self.counters.entry(message).or_insert(0);
        *counter += 1;
    }
}

struct ServerReader {
    server: Vec<u32>,
    state: SomeState,
}

impl ServerReader {
    fn new() -> ServerReader {
        ServerReader {
            server: vec!(1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 9, 1, 1, 5, 6),
            state: SomeState::new(),
        }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        println!("Connecting...");

        for message in self.server.iter() {
            println!("Received {}", message);
            self.state.process_message(*message);
        }
        println!("Disconnected");
    }

}
```

An alternative (which may or may not be possible in your real example) would be to avoid borrowing in the loop, making it more like:

```
loop {
    // if next_message() returns an owned message, ie not still borrowing
    // self
    let message = self.next_message();
    // now no borrow left
    self.process_message(message);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. My first though reading your first suggestion was that I would get the same error, because getting a mut ref on `self.state` to call process_message would try to get a mut ref of `self` too, but your example works indeed... I'm not sure why! I guess that means I should do a little more reading about borrowing

Comment: You can separately borrow fields of the struct; the first bit of documentation I found is https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html

Answer (score 5):

Given that you don't need the full `ServerReader` for processing a message, you could make `process_message` a free function and just pass `&mut self.counters` to it. Then you have disjoint borrows of `server` and `counters`, which is fine.

Or if your non-`server` part of `ServerReader` is larger, extract that into its own struct, and make `process_message` an impl method of that struct.

Answer (score 3):

In order to allow mutability in an `Iterator`, you should use `iter_mut()` and work on mutable references (`&mut message`). Then, to avoid the additional borrow, you could just perform the addition in the body of the loop:

```
for &mut message in self.server.iter_mut() {
    println!("Received {}", message);
    *self.counters.entry(message).or_insert(0) += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for; this is a very simplified example, and I'm not a big fan of doing everything inline (which would end in a veeeery long loop :)